# How to customise the route in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter. For example, my website is `test.com`

My default controller is `Home`

`Home` controller code

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index($firstname = NULL, $lastname = NULL)
    {
        if(!$firstname && !$lastname)
        {
            $this->load->view('home_view');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "First Name = " . $firstname . "<br>";
            echo "Last Name = " . $lastname ;
        }   
    }

}
```

When a URL like `test.com` is entered, it produce output form `home_view`, and it is ok.

When a URL like `test.com/home/index/Michael/Clarke` is entered, I get this output:

```
First Name = Michael
Last Name = Clarke
```

I want above out on URL like `test.com/Michael/Clarke` instead of `test.com/home/index/Michael/Clarke`.

How can I remove `home/index`?

Comment: in your `application/config/route.php`, set this `$route['home']/(:any)/(:any)              = "home/index";`. This route will take you to `index()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `application\config\route.php`

```
//UPDATE
// to achive example.com/firstname/lastname, use this route.
$route['(:any)/(:any)']                  = "test/index/$1/$2";
```

In your controllar

```
 public function index($first, $second){

        echo "first ".$first."<br>";
        echo "second ".$second;

    }//end function
```

will print for `example.com/ARIFUL/haque`
as

```
first ARIFUL 
second haque
```

Comment: it is good but i want to same result one example.com/ARIFUL/haque instead of example.com/home/ARIFUL/haque

Comment: Change the `$route['home/(:any)/(:any)'] = "home/index/$1/$2";`  to  `$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "test/index/$1/$2";` I've updated the above code also.